# VSCode: Using language servers to extend client "grammars" and/or "snippets"

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, vscode-extensions

I'm aware that Language Servers already provide some great Events such as `onDidChangeConfiguration` but my wish is to either

- Alternate or extend the applied configurations of the package.json
- Include unincluded patterns of the `/syntaxes/<lang>.json` or `/syntaxes/<lang>.tmLanguage`

depending on the users settings.

If someone could provide any hint I'd be very grateful. Reason behind this is that I want to split up the snippets & grammars based on different categories such as mayor releases of the related language or common community language packages which can be optionally enabled/disabled.